# jquery - mouseenter/mouseleave only fires once

Tags: jquery, mouseenter, mouseleave

I have an image map that I want to show images based on which one your hovered over and dim the main image.  This is the code I have

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".firstGuyOne",".secondGuyOne").hide();

$(".firstGuy").mouseenter( function (e) {
    $(".jetGroup").addClass("activeTeam");});
    $(".firstGuyOne").addClass("visibleTeam");

$(".firstGuy").mouseleave(function (e) {
    $(".jetGroup").removeClass ("activeTeam");
    $(".firstGuyOne").removeClass("visibleTeam");
  }
).click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });

$(".secondGuy").mouseenter( function (e) {
    $(".jetGroup").addClass("activeTeam");});
    $(".secondGuyOne").addClass("visibleTeam");

$(".secondGuy").mouseleave(function (e) {
    $(".jetGroup").removeClass ("activeTeam");
    $(".secondGuyOne").removeClass("visibleTeam");
  }
).click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });

});
</script>
```

It is only firing once for some reason. I will have about 5-6 of these events.  It will work when the page loads than they just don't work after that.  I have tried hover but that causes flickering in the image map and works correctly though.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In first two events you have inconsistency.
First event ends with

```
$(".jetGroup").addClass("activeTeam");
```

If you want to add

```
$(".firstGuyOne").addClass("visibleTeam");
```

also in this event, you should write like this

```
$(".firstGuy").mouseenter( function (e) {
$(".jetGroup").addClass("activeTeam");
$(".firstGuyOne").addClass("visibleTeam");
});
```

Same goes with secondGuy